# Listbox First Item Selected in mvvm

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I am new to mvvm. I have a listbox in my silverlight application which is binded to a observable collection in view model i want to make the listbox with first item selected. I tired this but it doesnt work.

```
<ListBox Height="431" Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="77" Width="215" FontSize="13" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categorys, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryDataTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Name="lst_category">
```

then i added this in mainpage load of mainpage viewmodel

```
CurrentCategory = Categorys[0];
```

Can any one Help me

Comment: have you tried SelectedIndex?

Comment: You Should try This Way Also                                  CurrentCategory = Categorys.FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Make sure that the collection `Categorys` is filled already. You might need to use [AsycCTP, Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) or some other mechanism to first wait for the collection to be filled.

   > The [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes. The task represents ongoing work.
2. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in ViewModel exposing the `Property`,  `CurrentCategory` and raise the event of PropertyChanged from within the `Setter` of the `Property`.

   ```
   private Category _currentCategory = null;

   public Category CurrentCategory 
   {
       get { return _currentCategory; }
       set
       {
           if (_currentCategory != value)
           { 
               _currentCategory = value;

               // Update bindings
               RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentCategory");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now you can use the same piece of code:

```
CurrentCategory = Categorys[0];
```

Comment: i have tried it but my Categorys collection takes time to load from service and have null value.

Comment: So you should use AsychCTP await or some other mechanism to first wait for the collection to fill.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ICollectionView` and `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`. The CollectionView has all the functionality you need. For example `MoveToFirst()`.

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private ObservableCollection<Category> _categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
            private Category _currentCategory;

            public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
            {
                get { return _categories; }
                set { _categories = value; OnPropertyChanged("Categories");}
            }

            public Category CurrentCategory
            {
                get { return _currentCategory; }
                set { _currentCategory = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCategory");}
            }

            public ICollectionView CategoriesView { get; private set; }

            public ViewModel()
            {
                Categories.Add(new Category{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Cat1"});
                Categories.Add(new Category{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Cat2"});
                Categories.Add(new Category{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Cat3"});

                CategoriesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Categories);
                CategoriesView.CurrentChanged += OnCategoriesChanged;
                CategoriesView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
            }

            private void OnCategoriesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var selectedCategory = CategoriesView.CurrentItem as Category;
                if (selectedCategory == null) return;

                CurrentCategory = selectedCategory;
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public class Category
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should Try This Way also.................

List  c = new List

```
CurrentCategory = c.firstOrDefault()
```