# XAML Combo Box is Empty on moving back to item in collection

Tags: xaml, observablecollection

I have a Combo box and a Label :

```
<!-- Does not select appropriate value after moving back to current item in collection -->
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            DisplayMemberPath="ItemName" 
            Margin="8,2,8,16" />

<!-- Displays correctly after moving back to current item in collection -->
        <Label 
        Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ItemName}"/>
```

I can set an Item in the combo box, but when I move from and back to the current item in the observable collection, the Combo Box does not set the SelectedValue as I expect (it remains empty) - the Label's content is set correctly - and its bound to the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `ICollectionView` as I described here ([Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13121798/345189)).
The CollectionView takes care of your combobox and you can read and set the current item.
Just attach an event handler to the `CurrentChanged` Event from the ICollectionView.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
      DisplayMemberPath="ItemName" 
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      Margin="8,2,8,16" />

<Label Content="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.ItemName}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items= new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    private Item _currentItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items= value; OnPropertyChanged("Items");}
    }

    public Item CurrentItem
    {
        get { return _currentItem; }
        set { _currentItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");}
    }

    public ICollectionView ItemsView { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new Item{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 1"});
        Items.Add(new Item{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 2"});
        Items.Add(new Item{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 3"});

        ItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
        ItemsView .CurrentChanged += OnItemsChanged;
        ItemsView .MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    private void OnItemsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = ItemsView .CurrentItem as Item;
        if (selectedItem == null) return;

        CurrentItem= selectedItem ;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```