# Add an item to ListBox without access to its ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, listbox, selectionchanged

I have just upgraded a project from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 and have found that ListBoxes behave differently. Items are sometimes added to ListBoxes from the code behind using

```
this.myListBox.SelectedItem = new MyItemType();
```

This no longer fires the myListBox.SelectionChanged event and is causing bugs in the program. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Afaik this has never been a valid way to add items to a ListBox/ItemsControl in WPF. When setting, the `SelectedItem` should always be an item that is already contained in the Items collection (or compares equal to an existing item).

Comment: I agree with @Clemens Add item to items list and then select it. It's a wonder this worked before...

Comment: have yourself a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13121798/345189 ICollectionView.MoveCurrentTo(xxx) is your friend.